# Is it possible to get the hostname(sitename) at the time of registering middleware in Owin startup?

Tags: c#, owin, startup, pipeline

I have a middleware that needs options object to start. One of the properties is hostname.(I mean its to be set up like http://mywebsite.com and not the physical machine name). The middleware is configured to do some business logic at startup and so app.Run() and app.Use() isn't an option.

I also cannot hardcode hostname(as I run multiple instances with different site names), or get it from the config file, because:
1. its duplication of information which I could otherwise get from database, if only I knew the hostname
2. I wouldn't still be sure which one out of the many site instances I have, was invoked

```
var options = new MyMiddlewareOptions{
hostname = <hostname of the server hosting this app>,
.
..
...
//other properties
};
app.UseMyMiddleware(options);
```

How can I get the hostname at the time of Owin Startup since there is no request or Environment data available?

I have tried using inline middleware, and I get the hostname but by then its too late.

something on the lines of:

```
app.Use((ctx,next) =>
        {
            host = ctx.Request.Uri.Host;
            var options = new MyMiddlewareOptions
            {
                hostname = host
            };
            app.UseMyMiddleware(options);
            return next.Invoke();
        }
```

The above does give me the Hostname, but it is too late to register a new middleware when a request is already in progress and therefore it doesn't really do things it should.

Is there a way to get the hostname at the time of startup when middlewares are getting registered?

Comment: can you use an alias such as . \. or localhost.  Have you tried not setting the property to see how it defaults.   I have had reasonable luck with Environment.MachineName over the years but it rarely is the name from a dns perspective such as website endpoints.

Comment: No sadly MachineName wont solve my problem. I am running multiple customized instances of a site and I need to configure the middleware based on the instance of the site that was invoked to perform some business logic at startup. But so far, haven't gotten anywhere. Probably middleware's can never be parametrized with runtime values. sigh

Comment: I have a similar problem setting a cookie domain

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute way of getting the host name until the first request has been received. It depends on what you're hosting the site on. When it's self hosting, you can do `app.Properties["host.Addresses"]`. IIS Express however is a different story - that key for a start doesn't exist (I don't if there is a way at all).

Comment: This has a much better explanation for IIS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080036/get-url-information-in-startup

Answer (score 0):

Use the `app.map('pathYouWant', methodYouNeed);`
I have a example in Portuguese using this method.
Access [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/346130/owin-authentication-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-por-dois-pontos-de-acesso-diferente-asp-net), you can learn more about this.