# Get URL information in Startup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, middleware

In an asp.net MVC 5 project I'm using a katana owin based middlewere to handle the authentication. Inside the `Start.cs` file I have the `Startup` class with the `Configuration` method. 
Is there a way to get the full URL of the request inside the `Configuration` method? I need to get the last part of it to be stored in a cookie

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
     app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { ... }
     // something here to get the full URL

     // other authentication code here
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @LarryBud No, but the answer from Chris made me aware that I was looking the wrong way.

Comment: So what was your final resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Startup runs outside of the request-cycle. In fact, it only runs once, and then multiple successive URLs can be serviced before it ever runs again (when AppPool recycles, server restarts, etc.)

Long and short, even if you *could* access the URL, it wouldn't do you any good because it would simply be the first random URL that was accessed, which may or may not be applicable to whatever you're trying to do here.